# "Sorry person" vs. "Person sorry"

Tags: adjectives, nouns, attributives

> I'm talking about a sorry person about the exam.
>
> I'm talking about a person sorry about the exam.

I intend to mean "a person who is sorry about the exam".

Are these two sentences the same and do they meet my intention?

Comment: The first version is syntactic garbage. The second one is simply an acceptable "condensed" version of what you say you *intend* it to mean anyway. That's to say, the highlighted element in *I'm talking about a person [**who is**] sorry about the exam* is optional, so it can validly be discarded.

Comment: @FumbleFingers if someone spoke the second sentence to me I’d hear it as two different sentences. Even written, it’s a bit awkward. I don’t think it can be discarded in fact even if it maybe can in theory.

Comment: The point I would like to figure out is why "a sorry man about the exam" is not equal to "a man sorry about the exam", or why "an angry man about the exam" is not equal to "a man angry about the exam", whereas "enough money to buy a new car" is equal to "money enough to buy a new car."
@FumbleFingers

Comment: If someone has strong feelings about a particular subject, we have to say they are _angry about_ that subject. An _angry man_ could be one who is bad-tempered by nature. Also, we can't say _a sorry man_ for _a man who feels sorry_. In old-fashioned language, it would mean a rather pathetic, contemptible man.

Comment: @Jawel7: The reason your first version doesn't work is because the entire adjectival element ***sorry about the exam*** can't be split up. Single-word adjectives usually come *before* the noun they modify, but "phrasal" adjectives normally come *after* the noun. Note that although it would be slightly "quirky", we could in principle use hyphens to make your multi-word adjectival phrase function syntactically like a singe-word adjective, as in *I'm talking about a "sorry-about-the-exam" person* (scare quotes alert the reader to a "quirky" usage; in speech those words are spoken *very rapidly*).

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the first sentence is ungrammatical. "Sorry" is a never-attributive adjective and should not be used as a pre-head modifier in a noun phrase structure. "Sorry" can only be used attributively in idiomatic expressions such as "A sorry state of affairs".

Comment: The point I would like to figure out is why "a sorry man about the exam" is not equal to "a man sorry about the exam", or why "an angry man about the exam" is not equal to "a man angry about the exam", whereas "enough money to buy a new car" is equal to "money enough to buy a new car."

Comment: It depends on the adjective. Some adjectives can only precede (eg. _mere_). Some adjectives must follow (eg. _sorry_).

Comment: Can I find any list including adjectives functioning like "enough" ?

Comment: Where do you find the sentence "I have money enough"? I don't think that's a common way of saying it.

Comment: That's not common. However, it's theoretically correct. "Money enough to buy a new car" is equal to "money that is enough to buy a new car". No difference between them just as some native speakers confirmed as well. However, when it comes to different adjectives, there are differences and I don't know why.

Comment: That is no different from "The person [who is] sorry". This is an English construction called [Whiz deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/whiz-deletion/info); it is not a special lexical property of the adjective.

Comment: Basically, for "sorry" (or any other adjective) to be understood to belong to "about", it must be next to it, i.e. "sorry about" must be one phrase.  "A sorry man about the exam" can only mean that the man is about the exam, which, of course, is nonsense.

Comment: Also, "a sorry state of affairs" isn't actually an idiomatic version of this.  It's a different construction entirely - "sorry" there is being used in a different, rather old-fashioned meaning of "pathetic".